# JSON format conversion via PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json format and want to convert this to my customized format. I want to do this conversion using PHP. How can I construct the above mentioned JSON array format. I want to place duplicate value of "id" having validation different in an array, Here is my format:

```
[{
"id": "1",
"label": "Username",
"type": "email",
"sequence": "1",
"field_name": "af1",
"group_name": "login",
"validation_name": "required",
"validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
}, {
"id": "2",
"label": "Password",
"type": "password",
"sequence": "2",
"field_name": "af2",
"group_name": "login",
"validation_name": "required",
"validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
}, {
"id": "3",
"label": "Mobile",
"type": "text",
"sequence": "3",
"field_name": "af3",
"group_name": "educational",
"validation_name": "required",
"validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
 }, {
"id": "1",
"label": "Username",
"type": "email",
"sequence": "1",
"field_name": "af1",
"group_name": "login",
"validation_name": "data-minlength",
"validation_message": "Minimum of 6 characters"
}]
```

And I want this:

```
[{
"id": "1",
"label": "Username",
"type": "email",
"sequence": "1",
"field_name": "af1",
"group_name": "login",
"validation": [{
        "validation_name": "required",
        "validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
    },
    {
        "validation_name": "data-minlength",
        "validation_message": "Minimum of 6 characters"
    }
]

}, {
"id": "2",
"label": "Password",
"type": "password",
"sequence": "2",
"field_name": "af2",
"group_name": "login",
"validation": [{
    "validation_name": "required",
    "validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
}]
}, {
"id": "3",
"label": "Mobile",
"type": "text",
"sequence": "3",
"field_name": "af3",
"group_name": "educational",
"validation": [{
    "validation_name": "required",
    "validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
}]
}]
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are building the main array and filling it with these objects

Comment: Start with an associative array of `key=id` and `value=array()`. Within the value associative array, create an array for "validation" key and keep appending to it.

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `TRUE` as its second argument to decode the JSON into arrays, manipulate the array using [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), the [square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) and/or [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) then use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create the new JSON.

Answer (score 0):

im sure your problem is in your code that generate the json.

but if you still want to do that, you can register/save id that already processed into $var

```
<?php
$json = '[{
"id": "1",
"label": "Username",
"type": "email",
"sequence": "1",
"field_name": "af1",
"group_name": "login",
"validation_name": "required",
"validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
}, {
"id": "2",
"label": "Password",
"type": "password",
"sequence": "2",
"field_name": "af2",
"group_name": "login",
"validation_name": "required",
"validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
}, {
"id": "3",
"label": "Mobile",
"type": "text",
"sequence": "3",
"field_name": "af3",
"group_name": "educational",
"validation_name": "required",
"validation_message": "Please fill out this field."
 }, {
"id": "1",
"label": "Username",
"type": "email",
"sequence": "1",
"field_name": "af1",
"group_name": "login",
"validation_name": "data-minlength",
"validation_message": "Minimum of 6 characters"
}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
$temp = array();
$newArray= array();
foreach($array as $key){
    if(!    in_array($key->id, $temp)){
        $temp[]=$key->id;
        $newArray[] = $key;
    }
}
echo json_encode($newArray);
```